# SAS Reading CSV file using input statement

Tags: sas

I am using this code to import csv file in sas

```
data retail;
infile "C:\users\Documents\training\Retails_csv" DSD MISSOVER FIRST OBS =2;
INPUT Supplier :$32. Item_Category :$32. Month :$3. Cost :DOLLAR10. Revenue :DOLLAR10. Unit_Price :DOLLAR10.2 Units_Availed :8. Units_Sold :8.;run;
```

I need to get the Cost Revenue and Unit price in $ format[The Output sas data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQcym.png)

my dataset is [I need the same Cost, revenue, Unit_PRICE IN DOLLAR FORMAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo5xn.png) 
please someone help
thanks

Comment: You posted a photograph that looks like a spreadsheet, but your program is trying to read from a text file.  Is your file really a CSV file?  If so then it should only contain text.  Please show the lines of text in the file.  Do not post it as a photograph, instead put the lines of text into the question.

Comment: It is a CSV file

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING will not get you an answer any faster. It's aoso rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking us for *free help* to solve *your problem*.

Comment: I am sorry for that, i don't mean to shout. And i am very thankful for the the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INFILE statement does not take the REPLACE keyword.  In fact since INFILE is just saying where the input data is coming from there isn't really any logical feature that the INFILE statement might have that would use that name.

You need to attach the DOLLAR format to the variables if you want SAS to print the values using dollar signs and thousands separators.  You can either attach the format in the data step or in the steps that print the data.

```
format cost revenue unit_price dollar10. ;
```

Comment: I am able to import using proc statement. But i need to import using input statement. Please help